# Bi Publisher Traversing thru XML tags

Tags: xml, xslt, bi-publisher

I have a data structure of this format. I am looking to see if I can retrieve each tag in the xml. (There may be additional tags also) & check if there is value for it, if so, put it on a counter.
This is something I can come up with. But I am not able to find a way to identify what tags will be there

```
<?for-each:BAL_NAME_REC?>
<?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, 'COUNTER', xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, 'COUNTER') + 1)?>
<?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, 'COUNTER'),What to put here )?>
<?end for each?>

<BAL_NAME_REC>
<CTX_STR>Context String</CTX_STR>
<CTX_USER_STR/>
<TRU_NAME>Tax Reporting Unit Name</TRU_NAME>
<RUN_TYPE/>
<AREA1/>
<AREA2/>
<AREA3/>
<AREA4/>
<STATUTORY_REPORT_TYPE/>
<REFERENCE_CODE/>
<RECORD_SEQUENCE>Record Sequence</RECORD_SEQUENCE>
<BAL_DIM>Balance Dimension</BAL_DIM>
<MONTH/>
<PROCESS_DATE/>
<PROCESS_TYPE/>
<PLAN_TYPE/>
<AREA5/>
<AREA6/>
<TAX_UNIT2/>
<STATUTORY_REPORT_CODE/>
<PERSON_NUMBER>Person Number</PERSON_NUMBER>
<PAYROLL_REL_NUM>Payroll Relationship Number</PAYROLL_REL_NUM>
<PERSON_NAME>Person Name</PERSON_NAME>
<PAYROLL_NAME>Payroll Name</PAYROLL_NAME>
<PERSON_NI/>
<NAME1>Deferred Compensation 401k</NAME1>
<NAME2>Deferred Compensation 401k Catch Up</NAME2>
<NAME110/>
<NAME111/>
<NAME112/>
<NAME113/>
<NAME114/>
<NAME115/>
<NAME116/>
<NAME117/>
<NAME118/>
<NAME119/>
<NAME120/>
<NAME121/>
<NAME122/>
</BAL_NAME_REC>
```

Comment: Can you post what the expected output would be?

Answer (score 0):

Using pure XPath 1.0, you can use the expression:

```
count(/BAL_NAME_REC/*[text()])
```

to count the number of elements, children of `BAL_NAME_REC`, that are populated with a text node. Given your example, this will return `10`. Thee is no need to "traverse" anything.

Comment: The end result I am trying to achieve here is I want to set a counter variable with the value that is displayed on the tag value. & use this to create a table , so that I can achieve dynamic columns based on what tags are populated. For Ex. these tags are not empty, so I am looking to create a table just with these columns<STATUTORY_REPORT_CODE/>
<PERSON_NUMBER>Person Number</PERSON_NUMBER>
<PAYROLL_REL_NUM>Payroll Relationship Number</PAYROLL_REL_NUM>
<PERSON_NAME>Person Name</PERSON_NAME>

Comment: I am afraid you have lost me at this point. Please edit your question and add the exact result you expect to get in the given example - see: [mcve].